# Is there any currency conversion api that responds with realtime data conversion?

Tags: android, currency

i am trying to find a way to get the currency conversion rates on realtime basis , i found http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=1GBP=?USD was not working .could you please suggest any alternate way of doing this,thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using fixer api .
It has option for finding the exchange rates on previous dates also .
[http://fixer.io/](http://Fixer)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, but since the result is in xml you have to convert it to a POJO

http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx/ConversionRate?FromCurrency=USD&ToCurrency=GBP

Answer (score 0):

I'll recommend [CurrencyFreanks.com](https://currencyfreaks.com/). It provides real-time currency conversion, current and historical forex exchange rate, currency fluctuation, and IP to currency data through REST API in JSON and XML formats compatible. It has the following features:

- Reliable data as they source their data from various trusted Forex exchanges and Banks.
- You can get updates every 60 sec.
- You can change the ‘Base’ currency.
- It provides currency exchange rates for 179 currencies worldwide
  including currencies, metals, and cryptocurrencies.
- Supported codes for the endpoints are Shell, Node.js, Java, Python,
  PHP, Ruby, JS, C#, Go, C, Swift.
- Having free and economical paid plans.

**Here is the currency conversion endpoint:**

```
$ curl 'https://api.currencyfreaks.com/latest/convert?apikey=YOUR_APIKEY&from=USD&to=EUR&amount=500'
```

The JSON response will be:

```
{
    "date": "2020-12-08 06:20:00+00",
    "current_rates": {
        "USD": "1.0",
        "EUR": "0.8251"
    },
    "converted_amount": "412.5415",
    "query": {
        "given_amount": "500.0",
        "from": "USD",
        "to": "EUR"
    }
}
```